# Deleting from list

Tags: c++, algorithm, list

Im having a list like this:

```
struct List {
    int i;
    int n = 0;
    List *previous;
    List *next;
    List * head = NULL;
    List * tail = NULL;
};
```

Im adding elements to list and for example I have a list { 10000, 10, 200 }. Its creating it fine.

My erase function is like this:

```
List * erase(List * lista, List * elem) {
    List * pom;
    if(elem != NULL) {
        pom = elem->next;
        elem->next = pom->next;
    } else {
        pom = lista;
        lista = lista->next;
    }
    lista->n--;
    delete pom;
}
```

Now when I want to delete item (exactly this item, for others it's working fine):

```
erase(l1, l1->head->next->next);
```

I want to show result with function:

```
void showSequence(List * m) {
    for(int i = 0; i < m->n; i++) {
        printf("%i ", m->head->i);
        m->head = m->head->next;
    }
}
```

And for good result I need to call showSequence twice because for first time it gives me {0, 10} and for second (fine) {200, 10}.

Any ideas why?

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please, as usual!

Answer (score 0):

Your `showSequence` function modifies the `head` link. On the second call, `m->head` is at the last link.

```
void showSequence(List * m) {
    List *c = m->head;
    for(int i = 0; i < m->n; i++) {
        printf("%i ", c->i);
        c = c->next;
    }
}
```